# can anyone tell me how to click on I am a fresher link using selenium webdriver testing on following url

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

https://my.naukri.com/account/createaccount?othersrcp=24167&wExp=N&id=

i tried using following syntax:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='box')]//div[@class='freshercont')]//div[@class='icon fresher')]//button[@title='I am a Fresher']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='I am a Fresher']")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='userType']")).click();
```

If that doesnt work, use:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='fresher']")).click();
```

Comment: All are working actually there was some problem with my ecilipse

Comment: Okay, that's great. Anyway, it should be cleaner for your code and future reading to use less elements!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this XPath:

```
//button[text()='I am a Fresher']
```

Comment: All are working actually there was some problem with my ecilipse